# filter markers based on user input leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, filtering, leaflet, user-input, search-box

I'm trying to filter my markers based on a user text input but am unsure of how to get it to work.  I'm using javascript and leaflet.js.  This is the example of the code with a hardcoded filter, but i want to be able to filter the data based on a user input.

```
    var stops = L.geoJson(points, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) //functionality on click on feature
    {
    layer.bindPopup(String('Stop Name:' + ' ' + feature.properties.Stop_Name + '</br>' + 'Route:' + ' ' + feature.properties.Route)); 

    layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
        this.openPopup();
    });
    layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        this.closePopup();
    });


    }
    , filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return feature.properties.Route == '10';
}});
```

is there a way of setting

```
    filter:function(feature, layer){ return feature.properties.Route == 'USER INPUT';}
```

i already have a search box on my page but not sure how to parse the result into the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new geojson using the user input as the filter, using an event listener or on ('click') or .submit, something to grab the input and put it into a variable, then call a function that adds the new geojson.

Something like:

```
function onSubmit() {
  var results = L.geoJson(null, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return feature.properties.zonecode == userinput;
    }
  }).addTo(map);
  results.addData(stops.toGeoJSON());
}
```

You would have to remove the old results and add new ones, but this should get you started.